# Create a custom template just for one category

Tags: magento2, template, phtml

I want to change the template just for one category.
My first template referece which is work for `list_rent.phtml` is the following one:

```
  <referenceBlock name='category.products.list'>
      <action method='setTemplate'>
          <argument name='template' xsi:type='string'>Magento_Catalog::product/list_rent.phtml</argument>
     </action>
  </referenceBlock>
```

but when I try to set the template for details_rent.phtml it doesn't work, even I use the same syntax and `details_rent.phtml` is located in `product/view` and `list_rent` in product

```
  <referenceBlock name='product.info.details'>
      <action method='setTemplate'>
          <argument name='template' xsi:type='string'>Magento_Catalog::product/view/details_rent.phtml</argument>
      </action>
  </referenceBlock>
```

Can anyone give me a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code,

**Use reference Name as category.products.list**

```
<referenceBlock name='category.products.list'>
      <action method='setTemplate'>
          <argument name='template' xsi:type='string'>Magento_Catalog::product/view/details_rent.phtml</argument>
      </action>
  </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: you have try with above code inside backend category page layout update field?

Comment: i need to referace this  :<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.details" template="product/view/details.phtml" after="product.info.media">

Comment: you have to reference this block inside category page?

Comment: by default details.phtml is call from this referance  in catalog_product_view.xml   -<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.details" template="product/view/details.phtml" after="product.info.media"> What i try to do is to call a diferent phtml just for one category in my backend category - layout update xml